# error after login html page

Tags: php, javascript, html, extjs

so, i got this error in firebug after trying to login to my html page in localhost.
i'm trying to build a login page right now. using php and extjs 3.2.1

this is the error on the first of html line

DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"

my php code using php5.3.10

```
 <?php

ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="my_db"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="my_user"; // Table name 


mysql_connect("$host", "$Username", "$Password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$Username=$_POST['Username']; 
$Password=$_POST['Password']; 

$Username = stripslashes($Username);
$Password = stripslashes($Password);
$Username = mysql_real_escape_string($Username);
$Password = mysql_real_escape_string($Password);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Username='$Username' and Password='$Password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){

session_register("Username");
session_register("Password"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

and i just want to test the page login_success.php page first.

```
<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<!--  library-->
<title>Sign In</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./../ext-3.2.1/resources/css/ext-all.css"/>

<!-- GC -->
<!-- LIBS -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="./../ext-3.2.1/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>

<!-- ENDLIBS -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="./../ext-3.2.1/ext-all.js"></script>



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/forms.css"/>


<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./../ext-3.2.1/shared/examples.css"/>-           ->

<center><img src="image/logonew.png" width="900" height="420"></center>
<div id="Sign In" style="margin:auto;"></div>    
<style type="text/css">
div {text-align:center}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/sign_in.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not an error; that's a doctype string.  It's usually seen in the company of `<` and `>`.

Comment: yeah i know @pointy, but the firebug keeps highlight this doctype as teh error when i'm trying to login

Comment: Can you post exactly what your HTML or PHP page looks like?

Comment: Does it actually say "error" anywhere, this just seems like firebug logging a request

Comment: the firebug says >> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token and pointed to this first line of my .html code line <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

Comment: Are you using some Ajax requests to load js in the page?

Comment: Does it really have a semicolon after the greater-than sign?  If so, you need to remove it.